# Output only keys of nested array as string.

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a function that generates a multidimensional to represent a tree structure. A print_r of what it returns looks something like this:

```
Array (
    [A] => Array (
        [A1] =>
        [A2] =>
    )
    [B] => Array (
        [B1] => Array (
            [B1a] =>
        )
    )
)
```

What I need is a recursive function that output this in depth first order, like this:

```
A
  A1
  A2
B
  B1
    B1a
```

or just

```
A, A1, A2, B, B1, B1a
```

I have tried to solve this for hours now so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use recursive function eg:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    'A'=>array(
        "A1"=>1,
        "A2"=>1,
        ),
        "B"=>array(
            "B1"=>array(
                "B2a"=>1,
                )
            ),
    );

function print_key($arr, $depth = 0){
    $pre_str = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
        echo $pre_str.$k."\n";
        if(is_array($v))
            print_key($v, $depth+1);
    }
}
print_key($arr);
```

Comment: sometimes we get stuck，heng;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to recursively scan the array, since `print_r` already does it for you. You could just call `print_r` and then parse the output:

```
preg_match_all('/^[^\[]*\[([^\]]*)\][^\]]*$/m', print_r($arr, true), $matches);
$result = implode(', ', $matches[1]);

echo $result; // A, A1, A2, B, B1, B1a
```

### Demo

Comment: Clever! I like the simplicity but i'll go for the recursive solution if i need to mark up the result or make other more complex changes later on. Still like this one though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized I can just try to mimic the print_r function so I found a useable function here:
[php print_r nice table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386331/php-print-r-nice-table)